# Date picker from SwipeStackAdapter adapter

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-datepicker

I have googled alot. But i did't get the solution.

My issue is i have one fragment. In the fragment i am inflating  some cards ie the swipe cards. for that swipe cards layout im using SwipeStackAdapter to inflate the view xml.

The in one of my xml view im trying to implement the datepicker.

**TaskCardListShow.java fragment code**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.jmedeisis.draglinearlayout.DragLinearLayout; 

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import link.fls.swipestack.SwipeStack;

public class TaskCardListShow extends Fragment implements SwipeStack.SwipeStackListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private ArrayList<String> mData;
    private ArrayList<String> LayOutData;
    private SwipeStack mSwipeStack;
    private SwipeStackAdapter mAdapter;
    public int cardCounter;
    Context context;
    AutoCompleteTextView autoTextView;

    public TaskCardListShow() {
    }
    public static TaskCardListShow newInstance() {

        TaskCardListShow _TaskCardListShow = new TaskCardListShow();

        return _TaskCardListShow;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_card_list_show, container, false);

        mSwipeStack = (SwipeStack) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeStack);
        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        LayOutData = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new SwipeStackAdapter(mData,LayOutData);
        mSwipeStack.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mSwipeStack.setListener(this);
        context=getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        cardCounter=7;// write function for getting card count.

        fillStackCard(); 
        return view;
    }

    private void fillStackCard() {
        for (int x = 0; x <cardCounter; x++) {
            mData.add(getString(R.string.dummy_text) + " " + (x + 1));
            LayOutData.add(getString(R.string.str_card)+ (x + 1));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onViewSwipedToRight(int position) {
        String swipedElement = mAdapter.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewSwipedToLeft(int position) {
        String swipedElement = mAdapter.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStackEmpty() {

        removeTaskCardFragment();
    }
    public void removeTaskCardFragment(){
        FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        TaskCardListShow _TaskCardListShowFragment = new TaskCardListShow();
        mFragmentTransaction.remove(_TaskCardListShowFragment);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
        manager.popBackStack();
    }

    public class SwipeStackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<String> mData;
        private List<String> LayOutData;
        DragLinearLayout dragDropAndroidLinearLayout;

        public SwipeStackAdapter(List<String> data,List<String> Ldata) {
            this.mData = data;
            this.LayOutData = Ldata;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String LName=LayOutData.get(position);

            try {
                int id = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().
                        getIdentifier(LName, "layout", getActivity().getPackageName());
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(id, parent, false);


                if(position==4){ // my date picker layout will come this postion.

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return convertView;
        }


}
```

**card_4.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation_large"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/TxtQuestion">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="Date picker template"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TxtQuestion"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/dpResult"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Can you please guide me to do this. I have tried lots of method but it is not working i my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by,

**in my adapter**

```
final TextView _dpResult=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dpResult);
_dpResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment( );
                                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
                            }
                        });
```

**SelectDateFragment**

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
    }
    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        TextView dpResult= (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dpResult);
        dpResult.setText(year+"-"+month+"-"+day);
    }
}
```

**The xml coding for the date picker is**

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dpResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="yyyy-mm-dd" />
```

Now i am able see the date-picker on my card. Thanks